# add node to treeview & add row to txt file?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I need until with add node to treeview a row is added to txt file

for example :

> node 1    =====>  id  name  famile
>                              1   test  test1
>
> node 2    =====>  id  name  famile
>                              2   test2  test3

when delete node , delete  one row of txt file Relating to node ?

```
        static void Write(DataTable dt, string outputFilePath)
    {
        int[] maxLengths = new int[dt.Columns.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            maxLengths[i] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.Length;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNull(i))
                {
                    int length = row[i].ToString().Length;

                    if (length > maxLengths[i])
                    {
                        maxLengths[i] = length;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, false))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.PadRight(maxLengths[i] + 2));
            }

            sw.WriteLine();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!row.IsNull(i))
                    {
                        sw.Write(row[i].ToString().PadRight(maxLengths[i] + 2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw.Write(new string(' ', maxLengths[i] + 2));
                    }
                }

                sw.WriteLine();
            }

            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

my add item :

```
        private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbType2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (cmbType2.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                PTypeS.Enabled = true;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("SType");
                dt.Columns.Add("DType");
                dt.Rows.Add("test", "test2");
                Write(dt, Application.StartupPath + "\\report\\WriteLines.txt");

            }
            else if (cmbType2.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                PTypeS.Enabled = true;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("SType");
                dt.Columns.Add("DType");
                dt.Rows.Add("test", "test2");
                Write(dt, Application.StartupPath + "\\report\\WriteLines.txt");

            }



            AddNodes(cmbType2.SelectedItem.ToString());


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("err");

        }
    }
```

my problem is related to connecting treeview node with txt file line ?
sorry my weak english !!

Comment: You want to iterate through a file (reading line by line, I presume), split each token by a known char separator and add those to a treeview? Also, you want to implement a delete functionality where the row which matches the selected node would be deleted aswell as said node. I'd advise you to edit your original post if this is what you truly intend. Furthermore, show us some of your previous attemps at making this work.

Comment: What is `Write` ? Implementation would be helpful.